# "Empty Response" after applying ClusterRole?

Tags: kubernetes, loadbalancer

Trying to apply an admin like ClusterRole to my cluster for testing and then tie to a binding with a ServiceAccount. but whenever I apply my service account to my deployment, it breaks my LoadBalancer URL and I can no longer see my webpage. If I remove the serviceAccountName from my deployment the URL http://elb.aws.com works however; if I add my ClusterRole, I get an "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" from the load balancer.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: admin-service-account
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

My cluster ROle binding is as follows:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-cluster-role-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-service-account
  namespace: test
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin-cluster-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

My deployment looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: admin-service-account
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: somerepo/test
```

Load Balancer config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: test
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http-test-port
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the informations mentioned in the manifests are exact, then:

1- Your `ClusterRole` name  is `admin-service-account`, but when you create the `ClusterRoleBinding` it is `admin-cluster-role` , this is incoherent. Please use the same name in both places!

2- In your deployment manifest file you didn't specify the namespace, so if your default namespace is not `test` then it won't work, make sure the service Account `admin-service-account` is created in the same namespace as the deployment.